# How to render only part of map and show only part of it?

Tags: libgdx, tiled

I have map size 40000X20000, **I want to render only 2048X2048 and show on the screen only 1200X600 pixle, How I do That?**

In other words, think that I have Large Map ,I dont want to render all the 40000X20000 I want to render only the smaller map 2048X2048

My screen allow me to show 1200X600 Pixle.

Example.
[image]

My Code:

```
public class LibgdxGame extends ApplicationAdapter {
    static final float WORLD_WIDTH = 40000.0f;
    static final float WORLD_HEIGHT = 20000.0f;

//  Define viewoport
    private static final float VIRTUAL_WIDTH = 1200.0f;
    private static final float VIRTUAL_HEIGHT = 600.0f;
    // Move camera around
    private static final float CAMERA_SPEED = 60.0f;

    private OrthographicCamera camera;
    private Viewport viewport;

    private TiledMap map;
    private TmxMapLoader loader;
    private OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer renderer;
    private Vector2 direction;


    @Override
    public void create () {



        camera = new OrthographicCamera(15000, 15000);

        viewport = new FitViewport(VIRTUAL_WIDTH, VIRTUAL_HEIGHT, camera);
        camera.position.set(10900, 10800, 0);
        loader = new TmxMapLoader();//
        map = loader.load("40000X20000.tmx");
        renderer = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(map);

        direction = new Vector2();
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        map.dispose();
        renderer.dispose();
    }

    @Override
    public void render () {
        System.out.println("Render.........");
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0.8f, 0.8f, 0.8f, 1.0f);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        updateCamera();

        renderer.setView(camera);
        renderer.render();
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
        viewport.update(width, height);
        System.out.println(width);
        System.out.println(height);
    }

    private void updateCamera() {
        direction.set(0.0f, 0.0f);

        int mouseX = Gdx.input.getX();
        int mouseY = Gdx.input.getY();
        int width = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
        int height = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();

        if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.LEFT) || (Gdx.input.isTouched() && mouseX < width * 0.25f)) {
            direction.x = -1;
        }
        else if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.RIGHT) || (Gdx.input.isTouched() && mouseX > width * 0.25f)) {
            direction.x = 1;
        }

        if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.UP) || (Gdx.input.isTouched() && mouseY < height * 0.25f)) {
            direction.y = 1;
        }
        else if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.DOWN) || (Gdx.input.isTouched() && mouseY > height * 0.25f)) {
            direction.y = -1;
        }

        direction.nor().scl(CAMERA_SPEED * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());;

        camera.position.x += direction.x;
        camera.position.y += direction.y;

        TiledMapTileLayer layer = (TiledMapTileLayer)map.getLayers().get(0);

        float cameraMinX = viewport.getWorldWidth() * 0.5f;
        float cameraMinY = viewport.getWorldHeight() * 0.5f;
        float cameraMaxX = layer.getWidth() * layer.getTileWidth() - cameraMinX;
        float cameraMaxY = layer.getHeight() * layer.getTileHeight() - cameraMinY;

        camera.position.x = MathUtils.clamp(camera.position.x, cameraMinX, cameraMaxX);
        camera.position.y= MathUtils.clamp(camera.position.y, cameraMinY, cameraMaxY);

        camera.update();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the tiled map renderer already automatically renders only enough tiles to cover the visible area. Not sure what you mean by saying you want to render 2048x2048 if that is far larger than the camera's view.

Comment: @Tenfour04 is right. You do not need to scessior or such. Depending on the viewport the tiledmaprender will only render the needed parts and does this very effective. But still try to avoid having a huge amount of tiles in the view. Increase tile size(combine 4 to 1 for example). Always test the performance.

Answer (score -1):

There are various way to do it, though no one is perfectly optimised. I tried to do this a few days ago. I have tried to use:

1. Spritecache ; which is the best option if you have a static map, no changing of tiles. Though you have a limit to buffer which is 5640 tiles/texture I guess.
2. Use Scessior Stack approach, which seems complicated to me, you can simply crop the needed texture region and show it as map. But this is not a good solution.
3. I would better go with this approach. I took two tmx file one is the large_map.tmx with all the detailed tiles and layer; and then took another small small_map.tmx which only contains 1/2 layers with no tiles. Then took two sets of loader, renderer and simply just copied the needs cells in the small area(2048X2048) from the large_map to small_map and render only the small map. Now you can use this map for dynamically change your tiles and show animation as it only loads the small tmx file.